# onEdit function Sort multiple sheets / same spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create the same onEdit() function for multiple sheets where the function is only triggered when a value in Column C (3) for one of the sheets has been added.

Unfortunately I can't manage to get this script running by simply copying the script for each seperate sheet. Is there a way that I can use one single onEdit function for all sheets?

**What I have so far for 1 specific sheet:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  multiSortColumns(e);
}
function multiSortColumns(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.getValue()!='') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('FASHION NL');
    var range = sheet.getRange("A5:bY600");
    range.sort({column:11,ascending:true});
    ss.toast('Sort complete.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `Is there a way that I can use one single onEdit function for all sheets?`, in this case, when `onEdit` trigger is used, you want to use `range.sort({column:11,ascending:true});` to all sheets? Or, `onEdit` trigger is used, you want to use `range.sort({column:11,ascending:true});` to the active sheet, and you want to use this for all sheets?

In this answer, I would like to propose both patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, when `onEdit` trigger is used, `range.sort({column:11,ascending:true});` is used for all sheets.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  multiSortColumns(e);
}

function multiSortColumns(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.getValue() != '') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
      var range = sheet.getRange("A5:bY600");
      range.sort({ column: 11, ascending: true });
    });
    ss.toast('Sort complete.');
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, when `onEdit` trigger is used, `range.sort({column:11,ascending:true});` is used to the active sheet. And, this script can be used for all sheets.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  multiSortColumns(e);
}

function multiSortColumns(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.getValue() != '') {
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("A5:bY600");
    range.sort({ column: 11, ascending: true });
    e.source.toast('Sort complete.');
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, when the size (cells) of the sheet is smaller than "A5:bY600", an error might occur. Please be careful about this.

### Added:

From your following reply,

> However it seems to be targeted towards every activesheet. However, the activesheet needs to be limited to a specific range of sheets because I have some hidden sheets that do not require this script.

If you want to use this script to the specific sheets you expect, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set your expected sheet names to `var sheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", , ,];`. By this, the script is run to the inputted sheets.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  multiSortColumns(e);
}

function multiSortColumns(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.getValue() != '') {
    var sheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", , ,]; // Please set your expected sheet names.
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if (sheets.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
      var range = sheet.getRange("A5:bY600");
      range.sort({ column: 11, ascending: true });
      e.source.toast('Sort complete.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was going for Pattern 2. That did the trick. However it seems to be targeted towards every **activesheet**. However, the **activesheet** needs to be limited to a specific range of sheets because I have some hidden sheets that do not require this script.

Comment: @Diego Kersjes Thank you for replying. From your reply, when you want to use the script for the specific sheets you expect, how about my added sample script? But, if I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Yes that works! Okay last question :-). What if I want this specific onEdit to be triggered when a certain text value is shown in Column D (4)? The text value is called "CHANGE OF DATE" and its visibility depends on the outcome of a formula in column D (4). So it is rather an onChange then an onEdit function?

Comment: @Diego Kersjes Thank you for replying. I'm glad your additional request was resolved. About your 3rd question of `last question :-). What if I want this specific onEdit to be triggered when a certain text value is shown in Column D (4)? The text value is called "CHANGE OF DATE" and its visibility depends on the outcome of a formula in column D (4). So it is rather an onChange then an onEdit function?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 3rd question. But, I would like to support you.

Comment: @Diego Kersjes So, when I could correctly understand your 3rd question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: okay no problem. So I would like to have something similar as the script you gave me, but with the following conditions instead:
1. Script is triggered either with onEdit or onChange by having the text value "Change of Date" appear in column D (4).
2. IMPORTANT TO KNOW: The text value that appears in column D (4) comes from a formula result that I already have implemented in the Google Sheets file.

Comment: @Diego Kersjes Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 3rd question. I'm worried that I might trouble you because I cannot resolve your various questions soon. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help a lot of users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your 3rd question, I'd be glad. Can you cooperate to do it?